# Kotlin Jackson generation objects from JSON

Tags: json, jackson, kotlin

Please help! I'm trying to generate object from JSON with jackson kotlin module. Here is json source:

```
{
    "name": "row",
    "type": "layout",
    "subviews": [{
        "type": "horizontal",
        "subviews": [{
            "type": "image",
            "icon": "ic_no_photo",
            "styles": {
                "view": {
                    "gravity": "center"
                }
            }
        }, {
            "type": "vertical",
            "subviews": [{
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "text": "Some text 1"
                }
            }, {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "text": "Some text 2"
                }
            }]
        }, {
            "type": "vertical",
            "subviews": [{
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "text": "Some text 3"
                }
            }, {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "text": "Some text 4"
                }
            }]
        }, {
            "type": "vertical",
            "subviews": [{
                "type": "image",
                "icon": "ic_no_photo"
            }, {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "text": "Some text 5"
                }
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

I'm trying to generate instance of Skeleton class.

```
data class Skeleton (val type : String,
                         val name: String,
                         val icon: String,
                         val fields: List<Field>,
                         val styles: Map<String, Map<String, Any>>,
                         val subviews : List<Skeleton>)

data class Field (val type: String, val value: Any)
```

As you can see, Skeleton object can have other Skeleton objects inside (and these objects can have other Skeleton objects inside too), also Skeleton can have List of Field objects

```
val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
val skeleton: Skeleton = mapper.readValue(File(file))
```

This code ends with exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Instantiation of [simple type, class com.uibuilder.controllers.parser.Skeleton] value failed (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException): Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.uibuilder.controllers.parser.Skeleton.<init>, parameter name
 at [Source: docs\layout.txt; line: 14, column: 3] (through reference chain: com.uibuilder.controllers.parser.Skeleton["subviews"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.uibuilder.controllers.parser.Skeleton["subviews"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several issues I found about your mapping that prevent Jackson from reading the value from JSON:

- `Skeleton` class has not-null constructor parameters (e.g. `val type: String`, not `String?`), and Jackson passes `null` to them if the value for those parameters is missing in JSON. This is what causes the exception you mentioned:

  > Parameter specified as non-null is null: method `com.uibuilder.controllers.parser.Skeleton.<init>`, parameter `name`

  To avoid it, you should mark the parameters that might might have values missing as nullable (all of the parameters in your case):

  ```
  data class Skeleton(val type: String?,
                      val name: String?,
                      val icon: String?,
                      val fields: List<Field>?,
                      val styles: Map<String, Map<String, Any>>?,
                      val subviews : List<Skeleton>?)
  ```
- `fields` in `Skeleton` has type `List<Field>`, but in JSON it's represented by a single object, not by an array. The fix would be to change the `fields` parameter type to `Field?`:

  ```
  data class Skeleton(...
                      val fields: Field?,
                      ...)
  ```
- Also, `Field` class in your code doesn't match the objects in JSON:

  ```
  "fields": {
      "text": "Some text 1"
  }
  ```

  You should change `Field` class as well, so that it has `text` property:

  ```
  data class Field(val text: String)
  ```

After I made the changes I listed, Jackson could successfully read the JSON in question.

---

**See also:** ["Null Safety" in Kotlin reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html).

Comment: Is there a way to use default values for constructor parameters during deserialization if json field values are null? also keeping the fields in data class non-nullable?