# Jackson Kotlin plugin not used by Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, kotlin

I can't force Spring to use Kotlin module for Jackson.
The problem is that Jackson can't parse JSON into data class.

```
//Exception
2018-02-23 13:29:09.046 ERROR 24730 --- [nio-9300-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/services] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [*.model.User]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method *.model.User.<init>, parameter name] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method *.User.<init>, parameter name

//JSON
{
    "name": "name",
    "surname": "surname",
    "email": "email",
    "password": "pswd"
}

//Model
@Entity
@Table
data class User(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        var userId: Long?,
        var name: String,
        var surname: String,
        var email: String,
        var password: String,
        (...)
        ): Resource() {
        (...)
}
```

I tried to config Jackson, but it didn't help much. What's strange, inside @Bean method where I configure ObjectMapper, everything works fine.
Also, when I added default values for non-nullable fields, they weren't overwritten.

```
@Configuration
class JacksonConfig {
    @Bean
    fun mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(): MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter {
        val mapper = ObjectMapper().registerKotlinModule()
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false)
        var user = mapper.readValue<User>("{\n" +
                "\t\"name\": \"name\",\n" +
                "\t\"surname\": \"surname\",\n" +
                "\t\"email\": \"email\",\n" +
                "\t\"password\": \"pswd\"\n" +
                "}")
        return MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper)
    }
}
```

What might be important is that model is in the different project than the application itself.

Kotlin version is 1.20
Jackson dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version> <!--2.9.4-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

And what I tried to this moment:

[All of these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324352/how-to-customise-the-jackson-json-mapper-implicitly-used-by-spring-boot)

[Similiar problem but probably different case anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959730/kotlin-jackson-generation-objects-from-json)

And some other, not worth noticing.

Comment: Seems that your mapper configuration is right. All should work.
Could you add logging for input request and could you add sample how you send request to controller?

Comment: Found the error, my previous analysis of problem was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had structure like:

```
abstract class AbstractController (...) {
    fun save(@RequestMapping entity: T) {
    (...)
}
```

And to enable it I used

```
class DeriveredController (...) {
    @PostMapping
    override fun save(entity: Derivered) {
    (...)
    }
}
```

Problem was with lack of @RequestMapping in derivered function.